# chkconfig tool couldn't work properly on SUSE 15

Tags: opensuse, suse, sles

I place the command

> khmac

to /etc/init.d, and execute

> chkconfig khmac on

on to make this command autostart when next start.

I had do this action on `SLES12,RHEL7,RHEL8` (and all the previous platform), `chkconfig` could work properly on all these platform (`khmac` could be autostart successfully).

When I do this action on `SLES15`, `chkconfig` didn't work properly. It's very strange, 
and I had checked the `Administration Guide` of `SLES15`([enter link description here](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled-15/singlehtml/book_sle_admin/book_sle_admin.html)), `chkconfig` is still supported on `SLES15`.

**Does anybody can help me**?

**SLES 15:**

```
linux-fatm:/etc/init.d # cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="15"
VERSION_ID="15"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15"
ID="sles"
ID_LIKE="suse"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:15"
linux-fatm:/etc/init.d # 
linux-fatm:/etc/init.d # pwd
/etc/init.d
linux-fatm:/etc/init.d # ll
total 80
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   565 Nov 20 03:28 khmac
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12288 Nov 22 21:43 .khmac.swp
-r-x------ 1 root root 17331 Nov 20 01:32 splx
-r-x------ 1 root root 28407 Nov 20 01:32 splxcore
-r-x------ 1 root root 13966 Nov 20 01:32 splxhttpd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0 Nov 22 21:56 xxx.sh
linux-fatm:/etc/init.d # chkconfig khmac on
linux-fatm:/etc/init.d # chkconfig -l

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
systemd configuration.

If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
To see services enabled on particular target use
'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

khmac                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
splx                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
splxcore                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
splxhttpd                 0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
xxx.sh                    0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

**RHEL 8:**

```
[root@localhost opt]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.0 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.0"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0 Beta (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.0:beta"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.0
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0 Beta"
[root@localhost opt]# 

[root@localhost opt]# ll /etc/init.d/
total 28
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 18325 Aug  3 08:33 functions
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   565 Nov 22 21:46 **khmac**
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  1161 Oct 16 09:34 README

[root@localhost opt]# **chkconfig khmac on**
[root@localhost opt]# chkconfig --list

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

      If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
      To see services enabled on particular target use
      'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

khmac           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

**SLES 12：**

```
KASSuSe12x64-202:~/khmac # cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12"
VERSION_ID="12"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12"
KASSuSe12x64-202:~/khmac # ll /etc/init.d/
total 200
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root   357 Apr 25  2017 after.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2964 Sep 27  2014 boot.apparmor
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   112 Apr 25  2017 boot.d
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2297 Jun 23  2014 boot.kdump
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root   378 Apr 25  2017 boot.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1536 Oct  9  2014 boot.udev
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root  5806 Mar  1  2013 cifs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3666 Oct  8  2014 dbus
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root   343 Apr 25  2017 halt.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1409 Sep 23  2014 inputattach
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13790 Sep 23  2014 ipmi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   568 May  4  2017 khmac
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12288 Nov 20 16:29 .khmac.swo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 May  4  2017 .khmac.swp
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 10015 Sep 23  2014 nfs
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 11138 Sep 23  2014 nfsserver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2030 Sep 23  2014 openct
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2606 Sep 23  2014 pcscd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8173 Sep 23  2014 postfix
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root  1264 Sep 27  2014 raw
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0 Sep 21  2014 rc0.d
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0 Sep 21  2014 rc1.d
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    96 Apr 25  2017 rc2.d
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   164 Nov 23 11:03 rc3.d
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    64 Nov  2 17:53 rc4.d
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   196 Nov 23 11:04 rc5.d
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0 Sep 21  2014 rc6.d
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0 Sep 21  2014 rcS.d
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2528 Sep 21  2014 rpmconfigcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1437 Sep 21  2014 slpd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5420 Sep 23  2014 snmpd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3562 Sep 23  2014 snmptrapd
-r-x------ 1 root root 17331 Nov  2 17:54 splx
-r-x------ 1 root root 28407 Nov  2 17:54 splxcore
-r-x------ 1 root root 13966 Nov  2 17:54 splxhttpd

KASSuSe12x64-202:~/khmac # chkconfig khmac on
KASSuSe12x64-202:~/khmac # chkconfig -l

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
systemd configuration.

If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
To see services enabled on particular target use
'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

after.local               0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
cifs                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
dbus                      0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
inputattach               0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
ipmi                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
khmac                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
nfs                       0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
nfsserver                 0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
openct                    0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
pcscd                     0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
postfix                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
raw                       0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
rpmconfigcheck            0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
slpd                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
snmpd                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
snmptrapd                 0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
splx                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
splxcore                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
splxhttpd                 0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
xinetd based services:
        chargen:            off
        chargen-udp:        off
        cups-lpd:           off
        daytime:            off
        daytime-udp:        off
        discard:            off
        discard-udp:        off
        echo:               off
        echo-udp:           off
        netstat:            off
        rsync:              off
        servers:            off
        services:           off
        systat:             off
        time:               off
        time-udp:           off
        vnc:                off
        vsftpd:             off
KASSuSe12x64-202:~/khmac #
```

**RHEL7:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

[root@localhost ~]# ll /etc/init.d/
total 108
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 17500 May  3  2017 functions
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   565 Nov 23 10:34 khmac
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  4334 May  3  2017 netconsole
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  7293 May  3  2017 network
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  1160 Aug  5  2017 README
-r-x------. 1 root root 17331 Sep  5 10:34 splx
-r-x------. 1 root root 28407 Sep  5 10:34 splxcore
-r-x------. 1 root root 13966 Sep  5 10:34 splxhttpd
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig khmac on
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

      If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
      To see services enabled on particular target use
      'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

khmac           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
netconsole      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:on    6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```